# jQuery Effects not working in when put in jstl forEach loop

Tags: jquery, jstl, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-tooltip

I have used jQuery accordion to display a list of questions in my JSP. Inside the accordion there are two operations that the user can perform, delete/update. If the question is not deletable (assume) then there is a lock symbol which appears in place of the delete symbol. The lock symbol has jQuery tooltip that shows why it is locked. 
My problem is the tooltip styling is appearing only for the first accordion. From the second accordion only the text appears while the styling is not there. 
(I am unable to attach screenshots because stackoverflow is not allowing me to do so)

When i do an inspect element I can see that the styling classes are not attached from the second accordion onwards. The accordion is displayed in a JSTL foreach loop. I'm not so familiar with jQuery that I can solve all these problems on my own so I'm not sure what my google/stackoverflow search string should be. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion( {
            collapsible : true
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#locked" ).tooltip();
    });
</script>

<div id="accordion">

<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.questionList}" var="question">
     <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${question.state eq 'locked'}">
          <div class="editModify">
             <img src="static/images/Locked.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;"
            title="This question cannot be Modified since it is being used in question paper/s" id="locked"></img>
          </div>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        Display links to edit and delete.
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I need to give more code. My JSP is too big hence I have pasted only part where the toolTip is present.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to understand what you are describing here

Comment: The problem is the tooltip will appear with the style used fromjQuery Themes(in this case "START") only for the first accordion pull down. from the second, only the text appears.